# Get month and year with this->db->where on codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

still problematic in my project . My own previous posts but no answer . I would like to call the Year and month of the mysql database of the results of the data POST.

This my controllers

```
public function report(){
$nomor = $this->input->post('nomor_reseller');
$bulan = $this->input->post('month'); // YYYY-MM

$report_data = $this->hasil_m->get_data($nomor, $bulan );
}
```

if only the month who called her work but if I enter the year and month did not work

This my models

```
function get_data($nomor,$bulan) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tb_pelanggan as pel');
    $this->db->join('tb_produk as pro', 'pel.id_barcode  = pro.id_barcode');    
    $this->db->select_sum('jumlah');
    $this->db->where('MONTH(pel.tgl_pembelian)',$bulan);
    $this->db->group_by('pel.id_barcode');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
        } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So can you clarify: This `$bulan = $this->input->post('month');` contains a value like `2016-03` right?

Comment: yes very precise @RiggsFolly , the POST month last 2 years and a month value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use DATE_FORMAT instead of YEAR and MONTH

```
->where("DATE_FORMAT(column_name,'%Y-%m')", $bulan)
```

Answer (score 1):

first your controller

```
public function report(){
$nomor = $this->input->post('nomor_reseller');
$bulan = $this->input->post('month'); // MM
$tahun = $this->input->post('year'); // YYYY

$report_data = $this->hasil_m->get_data($nomor, $bulan, $tahun );
}
```

and your model

```
function get_data($nomor,$bulan,$tahun) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tb_pelanggan as pel');
    $this->db->join('tb_produk as pro', 'pel.id_barcode  = pro.id_barcode');    
    $this->db->select_sum('jumlah');
    $this->db->where('MONTH(pel.tgl_pembelian)',$bulan);
    $this->db->where('YEAR(pel.tgl_pembelian)',$tahun);
    $this->db->group_by('pel.id_barcode');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
        } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice @Suhindra, but I just use the 1 input post , only months to use it only with datepicker